# Excel-Access ADO Update Values from multiple users

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-update, ado

I am building a database from Access where multiple users (around 10 users) can update it with excel/vba ADO connection using UserForms.

There is an issue where sometimes users are complaining that my data are not updating, something around 1 out of 10 updates are not working. Also there are no error reports.

Is there an optimal setup where my access database is not locked and there is no update conflict between users?

This is the code where I execute my query

```
SQL ="UPDATE table A SET x = 'something'"
bd.execute_query(SQL)
```

```
Public Function execute_query(ByVal SQL As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo error_handler

    If cn.State = 0 Then
        conect_bd
        blnConnection = True
    End If

    cn.Execute SQL, adExecuteNoRecords

    If blnConnection Then close_bd
    blnConnection = False

    execute_query = True

    Exit Function
error_handler:
execute_query = False

End Function
```

Comment: Is your database split?

Comment: Sorry but what you mean by "split"? I only use 1 table.

Comment: A front end and a backend. The backend would be on a server and the front end is local.

Comment: sorry im new into ado connections and excel interfaces with access. Is it the best  to split my access file?

Comment: Either way, I have a somewhat similar setup in one of mine. I use a combined database and a "buffer", the user's database checks the buffer database and if it isn't currently in use updates from that. Since the only time the buffer is ever in use is through a short bit of code I have an error handler that waits a second and then tries again. If for some reason it still can't get in after a few attempts it throws an error to the user to contact me because something is wrong. It has always gone off without a hitch.

Comment: Your situation is slightly different but the concept should work, just need to have it get the data from excel instead of an odbc that mine is.

Comment: I did understand the concept but i have some questions.1) So using ado connections will always have this kind of scenarios (multiple connections limitations)? 2) If i split my dababase do I have to update my front or backend access file?

Comment: Well the limitation is that a record can't be modified by two users at the same time. I don't know of anything that can handle that, or how that would work. Even my company's mrp software will throw a message saying it is in use. The concept behind splitting is everyone gets their own front end and that can be messed with however it needs to be. The backend is rarely modified and just contains the raw data. In what I am proposing you are essentially created a linked table from the backend to the excel but without a link. It refreshes when they push the button or whatever method you have going.

Comment: By "record" you mean a table or a single cell from my database row? In my case, users updates different rows, so there wouldn't be a problem?
Their own front, can it be a userform from Excel? So I need one workbook for each user? Im currently using a single read-only workbook to all my users.

Comment: A record is the entire row, I believe the lock affects the record above and below as well. You can create a connection from excel to access that shouldn’t be a problem there, the benefit of access is you can have multiple users in there at once (minus the record lock). A single read only excel book is going to be problematic it’s just not meant for that many users. By the sounds of it a basic split database would work for your needs.

Comment: For updates, should I connect to "be.accdb" or ".accdb"?

Comment: Seems like you're using a persistent connection object, which is very tricky with respect to locking. If you generally disconnect immediately after modifying or fetching data, you'll generally have fewer locking problems.

Comment: @ErikA in code terms how do I "Generally disconnect immediately after modifying or fetching data?" Is that some type of connection setup?

Comment: Well, start by not globally storing the connection, that already helps a lot

Comment: _So using ado connections will always have this kind of scenarios_ No. MS Access and Excel have these limitations because there is no "server" anywhere to work out consistenct. Server based database systems (like SQL Express for instance) do not have this problem because there is a single service that everyone connects to that guarantees consistency. I don't want to start a flame war, but MS Access is not really suitable for multi user systems. ADO is a just a driver that you use to connect, and if you use ADO to connect to SQL Server you won't have this issue.